# Alternatives to pseudoinverse for non-square system

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, projection-matrices

I am dealing with a system of equations
$$
\left[\begin{array}[c]\\d_1\\d_2\\d_3\end{array}\right]
=
\mathbf{A}
\left[\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{matrix}\right]~,
$$
where $\sum_i d_i=0$ and $\sum_i u_i=0$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is known. I wish to find the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ that satisfies
$$
~
\left[\begin{matrix}d_1\\d_2\end{matrix}\right]
=
\mathbf{B}
\left[\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\end{matrix}\right]~,
$$
in terms of the elements of $\mathbf{A}$. I have done so successfully using a pseudoinverse method using the projection
$$
\mathbf{P}
=
\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\\-1&-1\end{matrix}\right]~,
$$
and its pseudoinverse, $\mathbf{P}^+$ such that $\mathbf{P}^+\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{I}$. With these, I can then write
$$
\mathbf{P}\left[\begin{matrix}d_1\\d_2\end{matrix}\right]
=
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}\left[\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\end{matrix}\right]\\
\left[\begin{matrix}d_1\\d_2\end{matrix}\right]
=
\mathbf{P}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}\left[\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\end{matrix}\right]~.
$$
I then have my answer
$$\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{P}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}~,$$
provided I can determine $\mathbf{P}^+$.

I have the inkling that there must be an equivalent way of determining $\mathbf{B}$ that doesn't require explicit calculation of the pseudoinverse $\mathbf{P}^+$. What would that be? And for more general knowledge, is there a name for systems like my first system that can be reduced to the second system?